# Delete the row in the TableView out of the Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

Heey Guys,

So I can remove someone out of my TableView. I use this method to generate the tableview:

```
public void initialize(){
    TableView tableview = getUserDeleteTable();
    ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
    Connection c;
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        c = Database.getConnection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM User";
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
            //    System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            //   System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }
        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
```

.

```
and this on to delete a User from the Tableview:
```

.

```
    delButton.setOnAction( event -> {
        Object selectedItem = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        tableview.getItems().remove(selectedItem);

    });
```

So now im curious on whats the best solution to delete the one out of the database. the tableview is filled with a User object which has an ID name password email and points. What would be the best way to do it?

so as james_D said I should put User objects in the List. I got a User class with all the stuff it needs but how do I refractor it right?

Comment: "The tableview is filled with a User object...". Not according to the code you posted: in the code you fill the tableview with `ObservableList<String>`s. It would be better and easier to manage if you wrote a `User` class, and filled the table with actual `User` objects. Then you can readily get the ID from a `User` object and execute the SQL to delete one. I would start with that refactoring. (Also get rid of all your raw types: i.e. use `TableView<User>` instead of `TableView`, etc.)

Comment: so, If I change the List input to <User> it gives me an error at tableview.setItems(data) becausejavafx.collections.ObservableList<javafx.collections.ObservableList> cannot be cast to javafx.collections.ObservableList<sopraFx.extended.Model.User>. is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Yes. Populate the table with `User` instances instead of lists. In other words, make `data` an `ObservableList<User>` and `row` a `User`, etc.

Comment: So i changed that     ObservableList<User> data;     Do I need to change the CellValueFactorys to User, String ? because just like I did it with the changes above it has a problem giving out data.add(row). I dont really know how to refractor it do you mind helping me ?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials showing how to use a `TableView` to display domain objects (i.e. `User`s in your example). [Here](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/) is one; [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) is another. Once you set it up like that you can just do `User selectedItem = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` and then `int id = selectedItem.getId()` (assuming your `User` class has a `getId()` method). Then just execute the delete statement in the database.